# Why does my qt creater output a bunch of weird messages in the application output window after starting the application, even though a blank project?

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator, qtcore

Plotform: Windows 10
Qt Version: 5.14.2
Problem: When I click the run button to lunch the progrem,the there will output many message in application output window,even if this is a new blank qt project.

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sc46R.png)
[Qt Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw6Xi.png)

```
[PREVIEW] recv window msg, name:(Qt5QWindowIcon) hwd:(24118e) isvisiable(1) istopwnd(1) isTool(0) isPreview(0) pid:(31616)
[PREVIEW] recv window msg, name:(Qt5QWindowIcon) hwd:(24118e) isvisiable(1) istopwnd(1) isTool(0) isPreview(0) pid:(31616)
[PREVIEW] recv window msg, name:(Qt5QWindowIcon) hwd:(24118e) isvisiable(1) istopwnd(1) isTool(0) isPreview(0) pid:(31616)
[Hook] detach 31616, D:\Srchub\Qt\build-tets-Desktop_Qt_5_14_2_MinGW_64_bit-Release\release\tets.exe
```

I want to know how to close the output of theses strange message.

Comment: I have a hard time believing that comes from Qt. There's even a misspelling in the word "visible". Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I have exact the same issue. Including the strange isvisiable(1). Any created QWidget acts like this.